# How are 2D / 3D CUDA blocks divided into warps?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu-warp

If I start my kernel with a grid whose blocks have dimensions:

```
dim3 block_dims(16,16);
```

How are the grid blocks now split into warps? Do the first two rows of such a block form one warp, or the first two columns, or is this arbitrarily-ordered?

Assume a GPU Compute Capability of 2.0.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Threads are numbered in order within blocks so that `threadIdx.x` varies the fastest, then `threadIdx.y` the second fastest varying, and `threadIdx.z` the slowest varying. This is functionally the same as column major ordering in multidimensional arrays. Warps are sequentially constructed from threads in this ordering. So the calculation for a 2d block is

```
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x;
unsigned int warpid = tid / warpSize;
```

This is covered both in the programming guide and the PTX guide.

Comment: Note "column-major order" assumes that the dim3 is an array, rather than a struct. A more precise description is that `.x` is the fastest varying of the dimensions, `.y` is second-fastest varying, and `.z` varies slowest. How you associate `.x`, `.y`, and `.z` with rows, columns, slices, offsets, tree levels, or any other addressing within memory is up to you.

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate @talonmies's answer through 'Visual Studio WarpWatch' window for two consecutive warps (`dim3 block_dims(16,16);` and WarpSize = 32):

[image: First Warp] [image: Second Warp]