# How are threads in CUDA thread block split into warps?

Tags: cuda

NVidia GPU specifies that 1 warp has a fixed number of threads (32), then how are the threads in thread block split to different warps?

For 1 dimension thread block as `(128, 1)`, it looks the threads in `x` dimension are spit by 32 threads into different warps sequentially, but how does it work for other dimension sizes, like `(16, 2)`, will the 32 threads map to 1 warp in this case?

Comment: I wonder how a grid of 3 blocks each with 8 threads are scheduled. 3 warps on same sm unit or single warp or three sm units with 1 warp each..

Comment: see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257550/cuda-thread-id-assignment-in-2d-grid/14258158#14258158) for a 2D example (covers your 16,2 case), and it is also covered in [the CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture).

Comment: @RobertCrovella: This is not a dupe, because the other question does not specifically deal with the case of dimensions which do not fill complete warps; nor does talonmies' answer clarify what happens in those cases.

Comment: @einpoklum But is there anything preventing somebody posting an answer to the linked duplicate that *does* address those issues?

Comment: @AdrianMole: Actually, yes. The fact that the question there has an acceptable and answer. Only someone who visits there through here might consider doing that; but the appropriate course of action would be either to reopen this question, or to generalize/problematize the other question further. I think the former is the way to go.

Comment: I've pulled an additional duplicate link out of the comments and put it in the duplicate stamp.   I believe talonmies answer does cover the partial case, but in case not I've added verbiage to the additional duplicate link that does.