# How is my pyCuda indexing working?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, pycuda

I am trying to load a 3d array into pycuda (i'm going to load images). I want each thread to handle all the channels of a single pixel  using a for loop(this is an algorithmic requirement).

So far I have this working:

```
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
mod = SourceModule(open("./cudacode.cu").read())  

multiply_them = mod.get_function("multiply_them")

rows,cols = 800,400
a = numpy.random.randn(rows,cols,3).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.randn(rows,cols,3).astype(numpy.float32)



threads = 20
blocks = 16

dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
multiply_them(
        drv.Out(dest), drv.In(a), drv.In(b),np.int32(rows), np.int32(cols),  # notice it is rows, cols
        block=(blocks,blocks,1), grid=(rows//blocks,cols//blocks))

print( dest- 2*a*b)
print(np.unique( dest- 2*a*b))
```

and my cuda code is :

```
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b,int cols,int rows) # notice it is cols , rows  and not rows, cols 
{
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(row<rows && col <cols){

    dest[3* (row*cols + col)] =   2.0* a[3* (row*cols + col)  ]* b[3* (row*cols + col)  ] ; ## first channel of some pixel
    dest[3* (row*cols + col)+1] = 2.0* a[3* (row*cols + col)+1]* b[3* (row*cols + col)+1] ; ## second channel of that pixel
    dest[3* (row*cols + col)+2] = 2.0* a[3* (row*cols + col)+2]* b[3* (row*cols + col)+2] ; ## 3rd channel of that pixel 


    }
}
```

notice that in my cuda function, the rows and columns are switched. This whole code works fine the way it is.

I am able to say my code works fine because     `print(np.unique( dest- 2*a*b))`
prints 0.0

The `dest[3* (row*cols + col)]` style of indexing , I found from here https://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/GlInterop

My question is, why does max rows and max cols need to be switched in order for this to work ?

And what is the more logically correct way to get to do what I want?

I am new to cuda , so please be patient as I may ask questions that will probably be very stupid

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays use [row-major ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) by default. Threads within CUDA blocks are [numbered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6177473/681865) so that `threadIdx.x` is the fastest varying dimension, and `threadIdx.z` is the slowest (functionally equivalent to column major ordering). So if you wish to access row-major ordered data, as you would in a default ordered numpy array, and maintain access ordering which allows [memory coalescing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5041328/681865), then you should "reverse" the use of the x and y dimensions within a block. If your numpy array was column major ordered (`order='F'`), then you would not do this.

That is why your code works correctly when your intuition is that it should not.

Comment: just swapping the col and row variable names made it work. 
Can you tell me the general formula for this : 
dest[3* (row*cols + col)+1] 
And is there any potential problems why using my way of indexing ? (after swapping x and y like you mentioned)